# Is it possible to change another button text when a button is clicked in recyclerview?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

So I'm trying to create a game shop where user can buy and equip the item. I'm displaying an image and a button for the recyclerview item.

When the user buys all items already, the button have the text "EQUIP". When the user click "EQUIP" the button text should change to "EQUIPPED". Right now, I am able to change the button text from "EQUIP" to "EQUIPPED", but I want the other button text to revert to "EQUIP" and only one button can be "EQUIPPED"

Answer (score 0):

so I'll assume that "EQUIP" is a boolean so you can change it in the item and the button "EQUIP" is updated with that boolean and you have a list of equipment you are showing in the Recycler View given that

```kotlin
val equipmentList = ...

fun onItemClicked(newItemPosition: Int) {   
  val newItem = equipmentList.get(newItemPosition)
  val newItemType = newItem.type /*example a hand glove */
  val oldItemPosition = equipmentList.indexOfFirst { it.type == newItem.type }
  if(oldItemPosition != -1) { 
    equipmentList.get(oldItemPosition).equiped = false
    notifyItemChanged(oldItemPosition)
  }
  newItem.equiped = true
  notifyItemChanged(newItemPosition)
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to specify that I'm using Java, but could you please explain this line of code? How does it return the old item position?

val oldItemPosition = equipmentList.indexOfFirst { it.type == newItem.type }